# Kotlin wildcard method

Tags: rx-java, kotlin

I'm having some problems using the `retryWhen` function in RxJava.

When I create a function to be passed to `retryWhen` in an `Observable`, I cannot call the `zipWith` function. It seems that Kotlin is expecting something that cannot be cast here.

In this example, `it.zipWith` doesn't work (some other methods are available, but not this one):

```
    val retryFunc = Func1<Observable<out Throwable>, Observable<Any>> {
        // zipWith is not possible to call
        it.zipWith<Int, Any>(Observable.range(1, 3), Func2<Throwable, Int, Any> { throwable, integer ->
            if (integer > 2) {
                return@Func2 Observable.error<Any>(Exception())
            }
            Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        })
    }

    Observable.just("1", "2", "3").retryWhen(retryFunc)
```

---

If I change the incoming parameters to `Func1<Observable<in Throwable> ...`, the `in` keyword make it possible to use the `zipWith` function. But after I changed, the call `retryWhen(retryFunc)` shows an error:

> Type mismatch: Expecting out Throwable, found in Throwable

```
    val retryFunc = Func1<Observable<in Throwable>, Observable<Any>> {
        it.zipWith<Int, Any>(Observable.range(1, 3), Func2<Throwable, Int, Any> { throwable, integer ->
            if (integer > 2) {
                return@Func2 Observable.error<Any>(Exception())
            }
            Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        })
    }

    Observable.just("1", "2", "3").retryWhen(retryFunc) // type mismatch here, expected out, found in
```

Does anyone know how can I receive and produce the same type in Kotlin?

Be able to create the `zipWith` and return the expected value?

Comment: This question seems familiar, this issue came up somewhere else.  The author of the [Kotlin extensions to RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin) is active on [Kotlin slack](http://kotlinslackin.herokuapp.com/) in the #rx channel, you can ask there and report back here if he had any further information.

Comment: I posted yesterday in slack with no response, but I think that was on general channel... I ll try in RX again, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

`it.cast(Throwable::class.java).zipWith`

Or this one:

`(observable as Observable<Throwable>).zipWith`

Casting with `Throwable` solves, I hope that Kotlin has another way (not depending on `Observable.cast` method).

Comment: Your 2nd flavour using `as` is idiomatic for casting.

Comment: You should define your retryFunc first parameter as invariant: `Observable<Throwable>` as zipWith as `retryWhen` and `zipWith` is disagreeing on variance. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html and http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/1s7h5gs9uqp1sf7t3bng6vaao7/f6ac4lnf541vdab9ek9cdfschn

Comment: @tommes Even use as invariant the IDE shows that need to be covariant (out Throwable)

Comment: That's sounds like an error. Are you sure you have removed all variance keywords? Which lines produces an error, when you mark the type as invariant?

Comment: At this point I'd remove the Func1 type declaration and let type inference resolve the type on the lambda.

Comment: This was evaluated as same as `Func1<Observable<out Throwable>, Observable<Any>>`, I just put the Func1 to be more readable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99727/discussion-between-tommes-and-deividi-cavarzan).